# Change SAS 9.3 default encoding

Tags: sas

How to change default encoding for internal processing of data in SAS? It is currently `wlatin1` but I want `UTF-8` as the default encoding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding Issue SAS 9.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183289/encoding-issue-sas-9-3)

Answer (score 1):

Do You want to change encoding for SAS session? 
You can specify the ENCODING= system option in a configuration file or at SAS invocation.

[change SAS encoding for Base SAS sessions](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/spdsug/64018/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n03fxw69e78sxjn1lk43y3ghx2ih.htm)

You can also change encoding for SAS tables in infile statement etc.

[change SAS enconding](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/63072/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0utx4w7x4exijn1wt7pk0srrxz5.htm)

Comment: I have made following change in sasv9.cfg file which was pointed by the config under "C:\Program Files\SAS93\x86\SASFoundation\9.3"

-SET SASCFG "C:\Program Files\SAS93\x86\SASFoundation\9.3\nls\u8"
-DBCS 
-LOCALE en_US
-ENCODING UTF8

but even that didn't do any good. The encoding is still wlatin1.

Comment: UTF-8 is not a double byte character set.  Remove the -DBCS option.

Answer (score 0):

SAS should install (as of 9.3) at least two language options in addition to your default language.  It should install a "Unicode Support" version (which is UTF-8) and a "DBCS" version (for Chinese/Japanese/etc. code pages).

Open the Start Menu, navigate to SAS, then open the "Additional Languages" folder, which should include these.  If they weren't installed properly (and you have to intentionally *not* install them starting with 9.3, so they probably are installed), ask your local SAS admin to re-install SAS with these.
[image: SAS Start Menu Picture]

If you don't have Windows, you may still have these.  Look in your SAS Home folder, then:

```
%sashome%/sasfoundation/9.3/nls/
```

That will have subfolders for each installed language; I have `en`, `u8`, and `1d` (for DBCS).  These each have pre-built config files for their appropriate code pages.  Use the appropriate config file (with then modifications made for your environment as needed).

Comment: making changes to the config file didn't even help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this entry to your SAS9.cfg file:

```
-ENCODING utf-8
```