# Reading Greek text into SAS

Tags: sas

My data has a name variable which has few Greek names. When Iimport data into SAS, I couldn't get the proper names. in place of Greek letters I am getting Question marks. Please help me out how to read data into SAS which contains in Greek letters.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199999/change-sas-9-3-default-encoding - it may help to open SAS with a unicode-supporting encoding.  If you have an older version of SAS, update the question with the version #.

Comment: Thanks Joe.. data reading properly when i run code through SAS unicode server.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `encoding='utf-16'` to your infile statemenet.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply..I have tried your suggestion, data was not read into sas and gave message in log as "WARNING: A character that could not be transcoded was encountered.". 
do you have any idea to correct this warning and read it properly..

Comment: Hi! That option was what helped me read the norwegian characters. There are very many different values, [take a look here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/61893/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002628552.htm)

Comment: Looks like `encoding='wgreek'` could be an option